# Add class not working on hyperlink

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

**jQuery**

```
if ($('.panel a').hasClass('collapsed')) {
    $('.panel a').addClass('no-print');
}
```

**HTML**

```
<div class="panel panel-default">
    <a data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#accordion" href="#collapse1" class="collapsed">
</div>
```

I have my jQuery and HTML above, I wanted to add the no-print, which triggers the no-print CSS style that won't print its content... However, it's not working. Is my jQuery wrong?

I have followed this instruction:

1. [Check to see if href has class, if so, grab the id](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13264252/check-to-see-if-href-has-class-if-so-grab-the-id)
2. [Determine if an element has a CSS class with jQuery](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/263232/determine-if-an-element-has-a-css-class-with-jquery)

I don't know what else to do...

Comment: Where is that `script` relevant to the rest of your HTML

Comment: You should wrap your jQuery code in the '$(document).ready();' event

Comment: Hello @MarkNijboer, I tried it, but it doesn't work.

Comment: @tymeJV that is the only script that I want to the no-print class, so when the user click the print button, then it wont display that area. Which when it dont have a class, it shows a content, and when it have the collapse class, it wont show the content.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Wrap your script code inside the `document.ready` event.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  if ($('.panel a').hasClass('collapsed')) {
    $('.panel a').addClass('no-print');
  }
})
```

[Js Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Lspzc3qk/1/)

Comment: what problem are you facing ? I have also added a sample demo which help you understand the problem.